# Google Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have used a Google Form to create a multiple choice survey. I need to assign one point to each answer that says "no issues" on the spreadsheet that it fills. For instance, if is says "no issues" in A2, A3, and A7, I need it to add up to 3 in the final cell.

How would I write this, and how would I enter it? I have been looking for two days, and cannot find a solution that I can make work. I have been using Google spreadsheets for a while, but I am new to writing anything for them, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is:

```
=countif(A1:A,"no issues")
```